# How to enforce arguments count to dll function using PInvoke in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have written a C dll containing a function that takes 4 arguments and returns a number. Then I created a C# application and called the dll function using PInvoke. Everything works fine. Then I changed no of arguments in the dll function from 4 to 3. But I did not change the method signature (DllImport method signature) in C#. To my surprise, the call still succeeds from C# but I get some unexpected value returned from the dll function.

I was expecting an exception but the call went through. Is there any way to strictly enforce arguments count when making function calls using P/Invoke?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to enforce parameter count to match. You simply have to get it right. The same is true for calling convention, parameter types and so on.

Unlike managed code, native DLLs do not have metadata describing how they must be called.

If you enable the p/invoke stack imbalance MDA then you will at least be able to detect the error you made at runtime.